# Is there any android emulator for general purpose can send hardware keyevent?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, keyevent

There is a toolbar for the android emulator in android studio for the user to "click" the volume button to send a volume KeyEvent to the application.

[android studio emulator tool bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUS44.png)

Are there other android emulators that can do this?

I have tried BlueStacks already but it will adjust the volume only instead of sending the KeyEvent.
For the application that may overwrite the default behavior of the Keyevent

(in this case, KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP & KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN, ACTION_UP & ACTION_DOWN),

how can I trigger those events in other android emulators?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other emulators, but if you can use `adb` with them, you can send keycodes with that

```
adb shell input keyevent 24 // KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
```

[There's a list of useful stuff including the keycodes here](https://gist.github.com/Pulimet/5013acf2cd5b28e55036c82c91bd56d8)